# How can I fix an error of spark application?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, clickhouse

I'm loading data from hdfs to clickhouse with spark job and get the error `DB::Exception: Too many parts (306). Merges are processed much slower than inserts. (TOO_MANY_PARTS) (version 22.3.44 (official build))`
Data is in parquet, volume 34 GB.
Path to parquet "hdfs://host:8020/user/stat/year=2022/month=1/day=1/101.parq".

My settings like so:

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("hdfs://host:8020/user/stat/year=2022/")
df.write
.format("jdbc")
.mode("append")
.option("driver","cc.blynk.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver")
.option("url", "jdbc:clickhouse://host:8123/default")
.option("user", "login")
.option("password", "pass")
.option("dbtable", "table")
.save()
```

I'm new at Scala & Spark
so thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

Use `async_insert`

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#async-insert

```
.option("async_insert", "1")
```

or `Engine=Buffer` tables, for older ClickHouse version

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/buffer/

Comment: thanks, @Slach, I tried it on test table and it is work, I also tried it on prod (the same structure and same engine, but there are some data already)  - didn't work(

Comment: what exactly you tried? async_insert? or Engine=Buffer?
which version clickhouse-server do you use on production?

Comment: 22.3.44, option("async_insert", "1")  tried it. data is loading in already existing table.